# How can i update the state in the function and stop the timer and store the time

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

When One card is clicked then the timer is start and when we click on the second card the first card timer time are stored and second card become reset and all the cards behaves independently to start stop and store the time but if we the previous card are same then the timer are reset.

This is my Function:

-

```
const CollegeTeacherGandhinagar = ({navigation}) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);
  const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(null);
  const [previousCard, setPreviousCard] = useState(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [previousCardTimer, setPreviousCardTimer] = useState(0);
const courseCard = ({item}) => {
    const startTimer = () => {
      if (!isPlaying) {
        const id = setInterval(() => {
          setTimer(prevTimer => prevTimer + 1);
        }, 1000);
        setIntervalId(id);
        setIsPlaying(true);
        if (previousCard !== null) {
          tutorApi.find(course => course.id === previousCard).time =
            previousCardTimer;
        }
      }
    };

    const stopTimer = () => {
      if (isPlaying) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        setIsPlaying(false);
        setPreviousCardTimer(timer);
        setPreviousCard(currentCard);
      }
    };

    const resetTimer = () => {
      setTimer(0);
    };

    const storeTimer = () => {
      setTimer(previousCardTimer);
    };
    const formatTime = time => {
      const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, '0');
      const seconds = (time % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    };

    const handleCardClick = () => {
      setCurrentCard(item.id);
      if (currentCard !== null) {
        stopTimer();
      }
      if (previousCard !== item.id) {
        // The clicked Card is not the same as the previous Card
        console.log('Previous Card is different');
        resetTimer();
      } else {
        // The clicked Card is the same as the previous Card
        console.log('Current Card is the same as previous Card');
        console.log('Current Card:', currentCard);
        console.log('Previous Card:', previousCard);
        storeTimer();
      }

      startTimer();
    };

    return (
      <View style={{margin: 10}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: currentCard === item.id ? '#ff5435' : '#D9D9D9',
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
          onPress={handleCardClick}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18}}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text>{item.description}</Text>
          {currentCard === item.id && (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10}}>
              <Text style={{marginRight: 10}}>{formatTime(timer)}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={isPlaying ? stopTimer : startTimer}>
                <Image
                  source={
                    isPlaying
                      ? require('../../asset/paus.png')
                      : require('../../asset/play.png')
                  }
                  style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    // Flatlist is a Prop which is use for the Scrolling the Items
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      data={tutorApi}
      renderItem={courseCard}
    />
  );
};
```